# How correcly make 3 images side by side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making photo gallery, and i was wondering how better to wrap images to make 3 images side by side, wrap each image into 
`<div class="col-md-4">`, or i can put all images into

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <img src="">
   <img src="">
  <img src="">
   <img src="">
</div>
```

What would be correct method?

Comment: is the size of the images always the same?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: yes, i tried there is no difference, but i want to know what is the correct method

Comment: by default images are replaced inline elements, so they naturally align themselves side by side: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRWLrv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <img src=""/>
</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <img src=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <img src=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: my question is should i wrap one image into col-md-4 or i can wrap all images?

Comment: You can use my code I provided and it will be side by side.
You can also put images into one "col-md-4" but set  the width of the image to be 33.33% so they take equal width(if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

> All Images in one `col-md-4` :

```css
.x {
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="x"><img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cute-funny-pug-life-shades-summer-dogs-puppy-animal-pictures.jpg"></div>
   <div class="x"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhsZRYQl-mSO-SY_VMRbWoeEycn9HbxKwqnI7IxOVb0eKJLpom"></div>
   <div class="x"><img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg"></div>
   <div class="x"><img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg"></div>
</div>
```